# How to split/extract complex string data c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In this scenario the data I could have in my string may look like below but keep in mind the ids are dynamically generated so this isn't static and could be more than 2 if you haven't caught onto that.

> ing:server blah blah, you. 2019,;:10-!gs.csd 
>   **1. id=value, otherid=value, pos=(22,22,33)
>   2. id=value2, otherid=value2, pos=(2g,2g,f)** info other info info info info etc etc.

**EDIT: How am I supposed to extract the individual values into strings afterwards from the string, the following does not work:**

```
String valueString = "csd 1. id=value, otherid=value, pos=(22,22,33) ";

String value = valueString.Substring(valueString.IndexOf("otherid"), valueString.IndexOf(",") - valueString.IndexOf("otherid"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with Substring since you have already way of expecting when to start and when to end on your searching.

```
string result = x.Substring(x.IndexOf("csd"), (x.IndexOf("info ") - x.IndexOf("csd")));
```

I start searching on the start of the word "csd" and ends with the word "info " (with space), since there is also a word of info at the beginning of your string.

The result would be:

```
"csd 1. id=value, otherid=value, pos=(22,22,33) 2. id=value2, otherid=value2, pos=(24,21,33) "
```